# MATLAB indexing by indexes in another matrix

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to generate a new matrix, based on index values stored in another matrix.

This is trivial to do with a for loop, but this is currently the slowest line in some code I'm trying to optimise, and so I'm looking for a way to do it without the loop, and pulling my hair out.
I'm sure this has been answered before, and that I just don't know the right search terms.

```
n1 = 10;
n2 = 100;

a = randi(n2,[1,n1]);
b = randi(n2,[4,n1]);
c = rand(100,100);

for i = 1:n1
    d(:,i) = c(a(i),b(:,i));
end
```

Comment: Although it is possible to do this without a for loop, this piece of code already runs pretty fast (I'm getting <1ms). What are the values for `n1` and `n2` in your actual code?

Comment: Just preallocating the array `d` will speed up this code significantly. `d = zeros(4,n1);`, like @BillBokeey did in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming the value of `n1` in your code is way bigger than in the example you provide, which would explain why it is "slow".

In order to do this without a loop, you can use [Linear indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html):

```
n1 = 1e6;
n2 = 100;

a = randi(n2,[1,n1]);
b = randi(n2,[4,n1]);
c = rand(n2,n2);

% With a loop
d = zeros(4,n1);
tic

for i = 1:n1
    d(:,i) = c(a(i),b(:,i));
end

toc

% A faster way for big values of `n1`
d2 = zeros(4,n1);
tic

a_rep = repmat(a,4,1); % Repeat row indexes to match the elements in b

idx_Lin = sub2ind([n2,n2],a_rep(:),b(:)); % Get linear indexes

d2(:) = c(idx_Lin); % Fill

toc

isequal(d,d2)
```

> Elapsed time is 1.309654 seconds.

> Elapsed time is 0.062549 seconds.
>
> ans =
>
> logical
>
> 1

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
n1 = 10;
n2 = 100;
a =  randi(n2,[1,n1]);
b =  randi(n2,[4,n1]);
c = rand(100,100);
idx = (1:n1);
tic
d1=(c(a(idx),b(:,idx)))';
[idx,idy]=meshgrid(0:44:400,1:4);
d1=d1(idy+idx);
toc
```

this is the timeing:

```
Elapsed time is 0.000517 seconds.
```

Comment: Now worries, just two more lines & it is working.

Comment: But you create an intermediate `n1` square matrix, if `n1` is large, this will be slower than the loop version, just because of the large memory usage. I’m pretty sure BillBokeey’s solution is faster even for fairly small `n1` values.

Comment: this is the time of 1st(ME),2nd(loop), & 3rd(BillBokeey): Elapsed time is 0.000616 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.001542 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000857 seconds.

Comment: Now do `n1 = 1e6` or `n1 = 1e8` and see what happens…